# Ubuntu Compatibility with ThinkPad W540 - Driver Installation

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, thinkpad

I am running ubuntu 14.04 on the Lenove W540 and I'm not sure how to properly install the graphics drivers. The laptop has the following specs:

Memory 15.3 GiB

Processor Intel® Core™ i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz × 8

Graphics Intel® Haswell Mobile

Graphics NVIDIA Quadro K1100M

OS-type 64 bit

I have tried several methods to install the drivers without any luck (I usually end up with a black screen during/after bootup). I'm guessing something is up with the xserver.

A summary of some things I've tried:

1. System Settings > Software and Updates > Additional Drivers

   - Currently version 340.93 is selected, but ...

     - Haswell graphics seems to be enabled by default
     - Using Nvidia prime to switch always switches to the integrated graphics (even if integrated graphics is currently active).
   - Switching to other available drivers in the list results in similar behaviour (discrete graphics inactive or black screen)

     - 346.96[proprietary, tested]
     - Nouveau
     - 346.96[proprietary]
     - 340.93-updates
2. .run file provided by Nvidia on their website
3. [This article](http://xmodulo.com/install-configure-nvidia-optimus-driver-ubuntu.html) (the command line instructions). The driver version suggested in the driver manager installer isn't available for me.

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566822/ubuntu-compatibility-with-thinkpad-w540) stating that the drivers can be properly installed but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to add a comment for clarification for the answer.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Ubuntu 14.04.4](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#Updated_Packages). It ships a modern Linux kernel 4.2 that can help nvidia proprietary driver to work properly with your card.

Also please upload the probe of your computer to the [Linux-Hardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org/) after the 340.93 driver is installed and the system is rebooted so that we can share your system logs for developers and understand what is going wrong with your installation.