# Whoopsie and NetworkManager seem to be crashing causing network connectivity issues

Tags: wireless, network-manager, lenovo, thinkpad, whoopsie

I've recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Lenovo W540 Thinkpad, and I am having issues with my wireless network allowing network traffic. The `/var/log/syslog` and `journalctl -xe` output during the problem is as follows.

```
Oct 15 18:41:34 phil-ubuntu whoopsie[2221]: [18:41:34] offline
Oct 15 18:41:34 phil-ubuntu whoopsie[2221]: [18:41:34] online
Oct 15 18:41:55 phil-ubuntu NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1508110915.3547] policy: set 'Home Internet Connection' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Oct 15 18:42:32 phil-ubuntu whoopsie[2221]: [18:42:32] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Oct 15 18:42:32 phil-ubuntu whoopsie[2221]: [18:42:32] offline
Oct 15 18:42:53 phil-ubuntu whoopsie[2221]: [18:42:53] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Oct 15 18:43:14 phil-ubuntu whoopsie[2221]: [18:43:14] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Oct 15 18:43:36 phil-ubuntu whoopsie[2221]: [18:43:36] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Oct 15 18:43:57 phil-ubuntu whoopsie[2221]: [18:43:57] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Oct 15 18:44:18 phil-ubuntu whoopsie[2221]: [18:44:18] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Oct 15 18:44:21 phil-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1903]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with c0:56:27:0a:28:10 [GTK=CCMP]
Oct 15 18:44:39 phil-ubuntu whoopsie[2221]: [18:44:39] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Oct 15 18:45:00 phil-ubuntu whoopsie[2221]: [18:45:00] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Oct 15 18:45:10 phil-ubuntu gnome-keyring-daemon[2792]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/7, but it's already registered
Oct 15 18:45:10 phil-ubuntu gnome-keyring-daemon[2792]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/9, but it's already registered
Oct 15 18:45:10 phil-ubuntu gnome-keyring-daemon[2792]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/7, but it's already registered
Oct 15 18:45:10 phil-ubuntu gnome-keyring-daemon[2792]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/9, but it's already registered
Oct 15 18:45:11 phil-ubuntu whoopsie[2221]: [18:45:11] online
Oct 15 18:46:40 phil-ubuntu kernel: thinkpad_acpi: EC reports that Thermal Table has changed
Oct 15 18:46:43 phil-ubuntu kernel: thinkpad_acpi: EC reports that Thermal Table has changed
Oct 15 18:47:48 phil-ubuntu gnome-keyring-daemon[2792]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/10, but it's already registered
```

For some reason, as long as I keep a constant ping going to something like Google or Bing, or even my network gateway, I don't get the `whoopsie` issue, and can continue using my device as intended. When I turn off the ping, the network connectivity goes out after ~30min or so, it varies a lot.

I'm not sure what else to search for or show for information, so please let me know and I'll make edits.

Answer (score 0):

As per the reference : https://gist.github.com/okapies/de0d08f9e3c8bcb2b76a33b68f62a48c

This might be Kernel issue:

Try to reinstall the current linux-header

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Wifi card going to sleep

To save power many wifi cards will go to sleep to save power. In some cases the card will not wakeup from sleep: [16.04 LTS wifi connection issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues/768268)

To summarize the solution in the accepted answer:

1. Get details of your PCI wireless card by running `sudo lshw -class network`
2. Get your card model info according to the product line.
   For instance, as you can see in the question description it says
   `product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter` so the model of my card is `RTL8723BE`

   Or product: `RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller`
   so the model of my card is `RTL8101/2/6E`
3. Give the permission `sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/config.d/`
4. Open or create `config` and add `SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8723be"` (replace `rtl8723be` with your own model number)
5. Then run
   `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`
6. Finally restart your system.